# Getting data from XML nodes

Tags: php, xml

I am a beginner on PHP and XML.

I have a XML file as below (partly):

```
<combination>
  <id_combination>2289</id_combination>
  <quantity>4</quantity>
  <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
  <reference>K10100.1B</reference>
  <group_name>Color</group_name>
  <attribute_name>Blue</attribute_name>
</combination>

<combination>
  <id_combination>2289</id_combination>
  <quantity>4</quantity>
  <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
  <reference>K10100.1B</reference>
  <group_name>Size</group_name>
  <attribute_name>1</attribute_name>
</combination>

<combination>
  <id_combination>2290</id_combination>
  <quantity>20</quantity>
  <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
  <reference>K10100.2B</reference>
  <group_name>Color</group_name>
  <attribute_name>Blue</attribute_name>
</combination>

<combination>
  <id_combination>2290</id_combination>
  <quantity>20</quantity>
  <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
  <reference>K10100.2B</reference>
  <group_name>Size</group_name>
  <attribute_name>2</attribute_name>
</combination>
```

And i desire to get an array as described below:

```
$id_combination => 2289
$reference => K10100.1B
$combination_name => Color: Blue / Size: 1
$quantity => 4

$id_combination => 2290
$reference => K10100.2B
$combination_name => Color: Blue / Size: 2
$quantity => 20
```

I want to join data with the same 'id_combination' nodes and then process it in PHP.

I tried to use "foreach" loop, "array_unique", "implode" and etc.. but wasn't able to get any success.

I would appreciate anyone would help me straight to result with the suggested code.

Answer (score 0):

i just did the following changes to your xml and have append new code and look and worked on my xampp server

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
        <combinations>
            <combination>
              <id_combination>2289</id_combination>
              <quantity>4</quantity>
              <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
              <reference>K10100.1B</reference>
              <group_name>Color</group_name>
              <attribute_name>Blue</attribute_name>
            </combination>

            <combination>
              <id_combination>2289</id_combination>
              <quantity>4</quantity>
              <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
              <reference>K10100.1B</reference>
              <group_name>Size</group_name>
              <attribute_name>1</attribute_name>
            </combination>

            <combination>
              <id_combination>2290</id_combination>
              <quantity>20</quantity>
              <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
              <reference>K10100.2B</reference>
              <group_name>Color</group_name>
              <attribute_name>Blue</attribute_name>
            </combination>

            <combination>
              <id_combination>2290</id_combination>
              <quantity>20</quantity>
              <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
              <reference>K10100.2B</reference>
              <group_name>Size</group_name>
              <attribute_name>2</attribute_name>
            </combination>
        </combinations>';
        $xmlobject = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        echo '<pre>';
        // this print an array of objects
        print_r($xmlobject);
        // this print the associative array
        print_r((array)$xmlobject);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually ment help about the php code itself to make necessary array. :)

Comment: yes .... this creates an array `(array)$xmlobject` have a look lower part of code, to do so you need some changes on your xml

Comment: I simply don't know how to combine and array nodes with the same 'id_combination' :) and ask help to write the sample code itself to do it. Some combinations has the same 'id_combination' with different data continuing which i want to join them in one.. for example: $id_combination => 2289
$reference => K10100.1B
$combination_name => Color: Blue / Size : 1
$quantity => 4

Comment: It's not the complete xml that i sent. It's a part of it which i need highliht. And i do not know to modify the xml file and it's downloaded from third party periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an XSLT solution as this is a typical need for the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) in XSLT 1.0 used to group nodes by various keys. As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) is a special-purpose language designed to transform XML files and like most general purpose languages, PHP maintains an XSLT processor.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl to be loaded in script below)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="idkey" match="combination" use="id_combination" />

  <xsl:template match="combinations">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="combination[generate-id() =
                                   generate-id(key('idkey',id_combination)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="combination[generate-id() =
                       generate-id(key('idkey',id_combination)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="id_combination|quantity|unit_price_impact|reference"/>
      <combination_name>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('idkey',id_combination)">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(group_name, ': ', attribute_name)" />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>               
        </xsl:for-each>
      </combination_name>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// TRANSFORM XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// ECHO OUTPUT STRING
echo $newXml;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($newXml);
$xpath = $xml->xpath('//combination');

$array = [];    
foreach($xpath as $result){
    $inner = [];
    foreach ($result as $node => $item) {        
        $inner[$node] = (string)$item;
    }
    $array[] = $inner;
}

var_dump($array);
```

Transformed **XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <combinations>
   <combination>
     <id_combination>2289</id_combination>
     <quantity>4</quantity>
     <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
     <reference>K10100.1B</reference>
     <combination_name>Color: Blue / Size: 1</combination_name>
   </combination>
   <combination>
     <id_combination>2290</id_combination>
     <quantity>20</quantity>
     <unit_price_impact>0.000000</unit_price_impact>
     <reference>K10100.2B</reference>
     <combination_name>Color: Blue / Size: 2</combination_name>
   </combination>
 </combinations>
```

**Array** Output

```
 array(2) {
   [0]=>
   array(5) {
     ["id_combination"]=>
     string(4) "2289"
     ["quantity"]=>
     string(1) "4"
     ["unit_price_impact"]=>
     string(8) "0.000000"
     ["reference"]=>
     string(9) "K10100.1B"
     ["combination_name"]=>
     string(21) "Color: Blue / Size: 1"
   }
   [1]=>
   array(5) {
     ["id_combination"]=>
     string(4) "2290"
     ["quantity"]=>
      string(2) "20"
     ["unit_price_impact"]=>
     string(8) "0.000000"
     ["reference"]=>
    string(9) "K10100.2B"
     ["combination_name"]=>
     string(21) "Color: Blue / Size: 2"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I will try it as soon as possible.